# How can I add a template class to stack array?

Tags: c++

I am trying to use a template class in the stack with an array. The code is running fine but when I added template class, the code generates an error. 
This is the error message. 
Error:
'stack' is not a class, namespace,
      or enumeration.

```
template<class T>
class stack{
private:
     int top;
     T a[MAX_value];
public:
     stack():top (-1){}
     void push(T element);
     T pop();
     bool isEmpty();
     void display();
     void getTop();
};


void stack::push(T element){
.......
}

T stack::pop(){
....
}
```

I expected to get an integer output if I declare the stack input as integer or double.

```
stack<int> s, or stack<double> s.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax for defining a member function for a class template outside the class definition is this:

```
template <class T>
void stack<T>::push(T element) {...}
```